# Why is my website working perfectly in FF but not in Chrome/IE?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

So yeah, I have no idea at all and I've compared the different files in DiffNow.

I really don't know any code to give you, since I don't know where to look anymore. It's built in php/html/mysql/jquery.

The main conerns are:
-Animations work pretty bad in Chrome and IE(On the live-server that is. On the test-server everything works flawlessy).
-Ordering isn't working in Chrome and IE (after confirming your form you should be able to get to the payment)
-Fonts are weirdly changed in Chrome and IE on the live-server.

I appreciate any help from you guys, thanks!

EDIT:

```
Line 1, Column 2: Element head is missing a required instance of child element title.

Line 2, Column 15: Stray doctype.
<!DOCTYPE html>

Line 4, Column 43: Stray end tag html.
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

I guess these are pretty critical. Got any idea on how to fix these?

I'm sorry if I'm giving you terrible explanations but I thought that maybe you knew the typical solution for a stupid error like this. Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, do you think that with the description you've given that your issue can be solved here?

Comment: @j08691: at least we will recommend running an HTML validator on the code and checking error consoles in all the browsers, which might be information he or she didn't already have.

Comment: *smile* well, if you use out-the-box animations it should work, relying on jquery crossbrowser compatibility

Comment: Browser difference is there, but no one can help you if you dont give the code or description of the issue clearly

Comment: @everyone downvoting is all great but if you think it should be closed then use the provided feature to request it to be closed..

Comment: @Ben - I don't think this question should necessarily be closed. If the OP would post some details this may be salvageable.

Comment: @j08691 sorry man I just validated the sites and found about 10 more errors on the live server. I will edit this thread with the information.

Comment: @Ben `Why Close`: Questions that are sufficiently off-topic, as outlined in the FAQ, should be closed by casting close votes. Questions that are sufficiently similar to older questions should be closed by casting close votes. `Why votedown`:Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post

Comment: @sarnold I did validate and edit the thread now. Thanks.

Comment: @mschr Yeah I think it's weird too. I don't know where to look :( I think it's already added since it's working perfectly on the other server.

Comment: @JaozaMedia: Fix your HTML on the live server first.

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't shown us any HTML so far, I'm just guessing, but the error messages here:

```
Line 1, Column 2: Element head is missing a required instance of child element title.

Line 2, Column 15: Stray doctype.
<!DOCTYPE html>

Line 4, Column 43: Stray end tag html.
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

strongly suggest that your HTML output looks something like this:

```
 <head>
              <!DOCTYPE html>

                                           <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

If you want [HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#doctype), I suggest re-writing your first few lines to look more like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>...</title>
...
```

See [the w3.org technical report for more options](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#syntax).